# Why $y_i$ becomes $(y_i-\overline y)$ in linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study

Trying to figure out why $y_i$ becomes $(y_i-\overline y)$ in the below expression for finding $\widehat{\beta}$. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image: yi equals (yi-ymean)]

Comment: The equality does *not* assert that $y_i = y_i - \bar y$! Writing out the summations for the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ should make it clear what is going on.

Comment: @whuber: is this your particular approach or is it forum policy to answer questions like this with a hint rather than a full answer? I'm new here and somehow trying to catch the tone.

Comment: @Stijn That comment responded to an earlier version of the question (viewable by clicking on the "edited ... ago" link). In that version the question was problematic because it relied on a false assumption. I was trying to get this point clarified (which the OP did quite quickly). In general, the best uses of comments are (1) help make the question better; (2) provide information that will help the OP find the answer themselves if it might already be on the site; (3) help the OP ask a different more appropriate question; and (4) provide links to other resources, related material, etc.

Comment: @Stijn (Continued) For routine, pedestrian questions that are formulated solely for learning rather than the practice of stats, machine learning, and data analysis, we expect the OP to apply the [tag:self-study] tag. For questions that obviously belong in this category, many of us respond as if that tag were there already. The site does have an explicit written policy that recommends ways--which include hints in comments--to help the OP learn how to solve the problem themselves.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: thx added that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)- \sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)- n(\bar{x})= 0$.

So, $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i) - \bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})y_i$.

The first equality on the second line follows by the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Definition) and because $\bar{y}$ doesn't depend on $i$ and may be taken out of the summation. The final equality follows because $\bar{y}\times 0 = 0$.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something essential that might be obvious to others, but what exactly do you do in between the last two steps of the last line?

Comment: @Mollart I'll edit my answer to add explanation.